# How do you maintain the imaginary part of a complex ndarray when transposing in Python?

Tags: python, complex-numbers, numpy-ndarray

I have an np.ndarray t which contains complex numbers, generally like so:
   {`[[ 1.52999954e+04+0.00000000e+00j -1.20004552e+02-1.11745858e-04j
   2.02035276e+01-6.53487824e+03j ... -1.20004541e+02+3.34968369e-04j
   2.02035276e+01+6.53487824e+03j -1.20004552e+02+1.11745858e-04j]
   [ 2.80499916e+03+0.00000000e+00j -2.20008345e+01-2.0]`}

It is listed as a (257, 256) tuple when I use the t.shape .

When I try to call this line:

```
d[:, c] = np.transpose(t[bb])
```

Some values are stored in my matrix d, but they have lost their imaginary components.  Does anyone know how to maintain this?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: with `a=100*np.random.sample(20)+(100*np.random.sample(20)*1j); a=a.reshape(10,2)` - `a.T` produces the transposition of `a` with the real and imaginary parts intact. - maybe you can give us a better example of your data so we can copy and paste it to test. Please read [mcve].

Comment: Is your matrix d created/initialized with a non-complex `dtype` (`numpy.float32`)? If so, you are doing an implicit type casting when you copy your complex array into a slice of your non-complex array.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably implicitly casting your complex values into regular floats by writing them into a float array (your array d).

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.empty(shape=(2, 128), dtype=numpy.float32)
>>> b = 100*numpy.random.sample(128)+(100*numpy.random.sample(128)*1j)
>>> a.dtype
dtype('float32')
>>> b.dtype
dtype('complex128')
>>> a.shape
(2, 128)
>>> b.shape
(128,)
>>> a[0, :] = b
__main__:1: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
```

You should ensure your matrix d is created with a complex dtype:

```
d = numpy.empty(shape=..., dtype=t.dtype)
```